ArcGIS Quick Capture Conditional Display
I'm trying to create ArcGIS Quick Capture project. I have Station names and responsible people for that stations.

When I click, for example, "Kuzey 27" in my Quick Capture app I only want to see the stations that person is responsible for. Is there any arcade guide I can use?

So what have you tried? Often tweaking the pop-up you can limit what is displayed?
